# Add a column to a table with JSON CLOB constraint Oracle

Tags: json, oracle, clob, oracle12c

I am trying to add a column to an Oracle Table with a check for JSON for the CLOB type column i am adding.

```
ALTER TABLE TAB1 (ADD COL_NEW CLOB CONSTRAINT CONS1 (CLOB IS JSON));
ALTER TABLE TAB1 ADD COL_NEW CLOB CONSTRAINT CONS1 (CLOB IS JSON) ;
ALTER TABLE TAB1 ADD COL_NEW CLOB CONSTRAINT CONS1 (CLOB IS JSON);
```

All the above fails with errors:

```
ERROR execute() failed with: ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here     
ERROR execute() failed with: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
```

Answer (score 5):

The syntax is `constraint <<constraint name>> <<constraint type>> (<<columns>>`.  You're trying to create a check constraint so your constraint type should be `check`.  You also need to specify the name of the new column in the `(<<column name>> is json)` expression, not the `clob` data type.  So you'd want `constraint cons1 check( col_new is json )`

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD( column_name CLOB 
         CONSTRAINT constraint_name CHECK (column_name IS JSON ));
```

Comment: this one says :  ORA-00908: missing NULL keyword

Comment: Probably because JSON functionalities are available starting with 12.1.0.2.